# Fading out all elements of an Android GridView but one

Tags: android, animation, view, android-gridview

I have a GridView in which I would like to handle onItemClick events by fading out all items except the item clicked.

However, with my current method of attempting this:

```
adapterView.animate().setDuration(250).alpha(0);
clickedView.clearAnimation();
```

`clickedView` fades with the rest of `adapterView`. I suspect this is because the animation is setting alpha on the entire GridView container, rather than its individual children.

I am looking for at least a somewhat elegant workaround to this problem. I could probably just iterate through all the visible children and have them each individually fade, but I feel like there is probably something smarter and simpler than that.

Comment: I'd suggest it may be easier to make a copy of the element, then show that and hide everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.

Try creating a new View as a copy of the clickedView, setting all of the properties including height, width, etc. as well as position.

Then show the clickedView, and hide the adapterView as you are.

Comment: Hm; I assume that the way to go in terms of copying would be to get clickedView's drawing cache into a Bitmap, and then extend View to use that Bitmap in Canvas.onDraw(). Something like that anyway, I'm not too sure. But I'm more unsure about how to get this resulting View to show up in the appropriate location on screen.

Comment: Looks like this worked for my purposes, but what I needed to do to make it happen was wrap the GridView in a FrameLayout, which allowed me to place the copied View above the GridView.

Notably, doing this meant I had to use an ObjectAnimator, because for one reason or another ViewPropertyAnimator did not work on the GridView if it was contained in a FrameLayout - I would've had to use the ViewPropertyAnimator on the FrameLayout, throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Thanks.